# For loop does not properly iterate through array

Tags: python, for-loop

When I run my code, only the first item in the array "listWP" checks whether it is in "dataGA." Tried a bunch of things, same problem. New to coding apologize for ignorance

```
import csv

f_GA = open('MS_GA.csv', 'rt')
f_WP = open('MS_WP.csv', 'rt')
dataGA = csv.reader(f_GA, delimiter=',') 
dataWP = csv.reader(f_WP, delimiter=',')
listWP = []
for row in dataWP:
    for i in row:
        b = i[29:]
        listWP.append(b)
for url in listWP:
    for row in dataGA:
        for i in row:
            if url in i:
                print (i + " ||is top site")
```

Current output is the first item of the array listWP checked through dataGA, i would obviously like it to be all items

Comment: could you provide [mcve] please? Some of the data or a dummy version of it to better see what you're working with.

Comment: use `print()` to check what you have in variables - ie. in `listWP`, `dataGA`, `row`, `i`, `url`. Maybe they have something different than you expect.

Comment: FWIW I don't think this deserves a down-vote.

Comment: i didn't see an easy way to link a csv file. first time on posting on stack overflow sorry if it is easy

Comment: i did use print() and the variables are what i expected them to be, thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader()` returns a generator. The first time you iterate through it you process all the elements. All the subsequent times get nothing, since there are no more elements to iterate through. You should convert it to a list.

```
dataGA = list(csv.reader(f_GA, delimiter = ','))
```

However, it would probably be better if you redesigned your data structures. Instead of all those nested loops, convert the contents of `dataGA` to a `set` and then just use `if url in url_set:`.